# Empty Array in Atom Live Server. Null on Local Machine

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I have created a shopping cart script for a mock ecom site. I created an empty array

`shoppingcart.cart = [] ;`

When I run my script through Atom Live Server on Atom Editor, it runs no problem and gives me my empty array to be filled with whatever items I click on. When I run it on my local machine, I get null. I'm so confused on how it doesn't work on both. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If anyone needs more details please ask.

Comment: Where did you define `shoppingcart` and what is it?

Comment: I define it in the beginning of the script right after I create the shoppingCart object
"var shopping cart = {} ;
 shoppingcart.cart = () ;"
It's an empty array in that is used to record whatever data is passed through it (in this case, the name/price/count of an item).

Comment: Is the space after `shopping` a typo? You speak of `shoppingCart` with capital `C`... is the spelling consistent in your code?

Comment: @trincot it is. I apologize. I'm typing from my phone which keeps auto spacing even when I say not to.

Comment: @trincot okay sorry about the typoes. Finally on an actaully computer. So `var shoppingCart = {}; shoppingCart.cart = ();` is the code that I have as my first two lines